# Laravel Storage S3 causing nesting level abort

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-5

I have a loop setup to fetch a function to get an image based on id and type. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, the loop is probably.

I can save files to S3 without any issues.

Helpers.php

```
use Storage;
//
public static function getImage($id, $type)
{
   if(Storage::disk('s3')->exists('/images/' . $type . '/' . $id . '.png'))
   {
      return Storage::disk('s3')->get('/images/' . $type . '/' . $id . '.png');
   }
}
```

causes:

```
FatalErrorException in Uri.php line 521:
Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. The code failed on execution of "exists" method. After a day of debugging and research I've found [article](https://return-true.com/uploading-directly-to-amazon-s3-from-your-laravel-5-application/) where instead of calling static method author get URL directly from 'Client'. This approach pushed me to rewrite a little bit code.

My old code:

```
/**
 * Check if file exists in storage and return full URL or $default value.
 *
 * @param $path
 * @param string $default
 * @return string
 */
public static function getStorageUrl($path, $default = '')
{
    return Storage::exists($path) ? Storage::url($path) : $default;
}
```

New version:

```
/**
 * Check if file exists in storage and return full URL or $default value.
 *
 * @param $path
 * @param string $default
 * @return string
 */
public static function getStorageUrl($path, $default = '')
{

    /**
     * @var $storage FilesystemAdapter
     */
    $storage = Storage::disk('s3');

    return $storage->getDriver()->has($path) 
        ? $storage->url($path) 
        : $default;
}
```

Update: in some places (with deeper nesting) new version of code also didn't work. As far as I understand the code should have as less nesting layers of code (Classes, functions) as possible. So to make it work I've rewrite it once again with less nesting:

```
/**
 * Check if file exists in storage and return full URL or $default value.
 *
 * @param $path
 * @param string $default
 * @return string
 */
public static function getStorageUrl($path, $default = '')
{

    /**
     * @var $storage FilesystemAdapter
     * @var $adapter AwsS3Adapter
     * @var $client S3Client
     */
    $storage = Storage::disk('s3');
    $adapter = $storage->getDriver()->getAdapter();
    $client = $adapter->getClient();

    return $adapter->has($path)
        ? $client->getObjectUrl(env('S3_BUCKET'), $path)
        : $default;
}
```